# How to authenticate AWS service using IAM role from Non EC2 machine?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have one window service which is deployed on on prem server which is using Access Key and Secret Key for authenticate but now that key are disabled and need to use IAM role for authentication

Any one help how we can achieve using AWSSDK in .Net framework 4.8?

This is my profile which is using for initialize credential

```
[profile]
role_arn = role
output = json
region = us-east-1
role_session_name = rolesession
```

C# code is as below

```
var credFile = new SharedCredentialsFile(appSettings.AWSProfilesLocation);

        CredentialProfile credProfile;
        //this._logger.LogInformation(appSettings.AWSProfile);



        credFile.TryGetProfile(appSettings.AWSProfile, out credProfile);
        

        AWSCredentials aWSCredentials = AWSCredentialsFactory.GetAWSCredentials(credProfile, credFile);
        _amazonSqs = new AmazonSQSClient(aWSCredentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
```

Comment: You can't do this. You need some access keys that you give you permission to assume role.

Comment: @Marcin I am providing access key and secret key in environment variable till its throwing error "Error in assuming role"

[Profile]
role_arn = role
output = json
region = us-east-1
role_session_name = rolesession
credential_source = Environment

Comment: Please update and rephrase your question and add more context on what you want to achieve. You first said that your key and secret is disabled and you need to use a role, but in the comment above you are stating that you do have them in place, and it's throwing an error. Try to fully describe what you have in place and what's your end goal.

Comment: @Nick access key is not going to use anymore but for try to authenticate using role and key both (for knowledge purpose) still its not working

Comment: Again, update your question wit more info and some paeudo-code that you are using

Comment: @Nick question is updated

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind putting back the error you are observing as well, as it has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

As @Marcin suggested in order to assume a IAM role you still need some way to authenticate to AWS before that (whether that's going to be by using a programmatic access for an IAM user or via [federation from external service like Cognito, ADFS, AzureAD, Duo, Okta,](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html) etc).

As [per the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html):

> You can then specify a source_profile that
> points to a separate named profile that contains IAM user credentials
> with permission to use the role. In the previous example, the
> marketingadmin profile uses the credentials in the user1 profile. **When
> you specify that an AWS CLI command is to use the profile
> marketingadmin, the AWS CLI automatically looks up the credentials for
> the linked user1 profile and uses them to request temporary
> credentials for the specified IAM role**. The CLI uses the
> sts:AssumeRole operation in the background to accomplish this. Those
> temporary credentials are then used to run the requested AWS CLI
> command. The specified role must have attached IAM permission policies
> that allow the requested AWS CLI command to run.
>
> When you run commands using a profile that specifies an IAM role, the
> AWS CLI uses the source profile's credentials to call AWS Security
> Token Service (AWS STS) and request temporary credentials for the
> specified role. **The user in the source profile must have permission to
> call sts:assume-role for the role in the specified profile. The role
> must have a trust relationship that allows the user in the source
> profile to use the role.** The process of retrieving and then using
> temporary credentials for a role is often referred to as assuming the
> role.

Based on your comments and explanation (the one in which you are saying that you are still providing access and secret key as env var) and the error you have shared in one of your comments:

```
"Error in assuming role" [Profile] role_arn = role output = json region = us-east-1 role_session_name = rolesession credential_source = Environment
```

I'm assuming that the IAM user which you try to source if there is one present at all doesn't have permissions to assume the role_arn you are referring to.

There has to be a trust relationship between the IAM user and the role it tries to assume:

Policy attached to IAM user:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:envuser"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Trust policy on the role itself:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      **"Action": "sts:AssumeRole",**
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/marketingadminrole"
    }
  ]
}
```

On how to use those in .NET there are good explanations and examples [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47124876/how-to-specify-aws-credentials-in-c-sharp-net-core-console-program) and in [this blog post](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/credential-loading-and-the-aws-sdk-for-dotnet-deep-dive).